# chrome extension validating a statement even if it is false

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am coding a chrome extension that checks if a string is contained in any tab's URL and if that's the case it closes the said tab and opens a new one to a certain address.

Code:

```js
function check(){
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
    windows.forEach(function(window){
      window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
        if(tab.url.includes("youtube.com")||tab.url.includes("instagram.com")||tab.url.includes("reddit.com"))
        {
          var newURL = "https://www.google.com";
          chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id)
          chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL })
        }
      });
    });
  })
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check)
```

It works, but instead of opening one tab it opens 3, and checking the error log reveals that it can't find a tab with the id matching the one it's trying to close (because it has already closed it) but proceeds to create another page (which shouldn't be possible because if it has closed all the pages that contain that link this action shouldn't be triggered)

It worked well a few hours ago, but not anymore, so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Does your code ever use the "google" variable? Where does your code assign a value to "newURL"?

Comment: For some reason, I changed the name of that variable when I uploaded it here but that's not the problem, the variable google should be newURL I just changed the name and forgot to change every occurrence here but it matches in my code, anyway as I said it works, but it just works 3 times, now that I restarted google it runs 2 times, but it should run only once. I edited the post and this is how it currently looks like. @ThomasMueller